# How to draw a straight across the centroid points of the barcode using best fit points Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

This is the processed image and I can't increase the bwareaopen() as it won't work for my other image.

Anyway I'm trying to find the shortest points in the centre points of the barcode, to get the straight line across the centre points in the barcode.

Example:
After doing a centroid command, the points in the barcode are near to each other. Therefore, I just wanted to get the shortest points(which is the barcode) and draw a straight line across.

All the points need not be join, best fit points will do.

Step 1

[image: a busy cat]

Step 2

[image: a busy cat]

Step 3

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont have the x,y elements Andrey uses, you can find them by segmenting the image and using a naive threshold value on the area to avoid including the number below the bar code.

I've hacked out a solution in MATLAB doing the following:

1. Loading the image and making it binary
2. Extracting all connected components using bwlabel().
3. Getting useful information about each of them via regionprops() [.centroid will be a good approximation to the middel point for the lines].
4. Thresholded out small regions (noise and numbers)
5. Extracted x,y coordinates
6. Used Andreys linear fit solution

Code:

```
set(0,'DefaultFigureWindowStyle','docked');
close all;clear all;clc;
Im = imread('29ekeap.jpg');
Im=rgb2gray(Im);
%%

%Make binary
temp = zeros(size(Im));
temp(Im > mean(Im(:)))=1;
Im = temp;

%Visualize
f1 = figure(1);
imagesc(Im);colormap(gray);

%Find connected components
LabelIm = bwlabel(Im);

RegionInfo = regionprops(LabelIm);

%Remove background region
RegionInfo(1) = [];

%Get average area of regions
AvgArea = mean([RegionInfo(1:end).Area]);

%Vector to keep track of likely "bar elements"
Bar = zeros(length(RegionInfo),1);

%Iterate over regions, plot centroids if area is big enough
for i=1:length(RegionInfo)
   if RegionInfo(i).Area > AvgArea 
       hold on;
       plot(RegionInfo(i).Centroid(1),RegionInfo(i).Centroid(2),'r*')
       Bar(i) = 1;
   end
end

%Extract x,y points for interpolation
X = [RegionInfo(Bar==1).Centroid];
X = reshape(X,2,length(X)/2);

x = X(1,:);
y = X(2,:);

%Plot line according to Andrey
p = polyfit(x,y,1);
xMin = min(x(:));
xMax = max(x(:));
xRange = xMin:0.01:xMax;
yRange = p(1).*xRange + p(2);
plot(xRange,yRange,'LineWidth',2,'Color',[0.9 0.2 0.2]);
```

The result is a pretty good fitted line. You should be able to extend it to the ends by using the 'p' polynomal and evaluate when you dont encounter any more '1's if needed.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you already found the **x,y** of the centers, you should use **polyfit** function:
You will then find the polynomial coefficients of the best line. In order to draw a segment, you can take the minimal and maximal **x**

```
p = polyfit(x,y,1);
xMin = min(x(:));
xMax = max(x(:));
xRange = xMin:0.01:xMax;
yRange = p(1).*xRange + p(2);
plot(xRange,yRange);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your ultimate goal is to generate a line perpendicular to the bars in the bar code and passing roughly through the centroids of the bars, then I have another option for you to consider...

A simple solution would be to perform a Hough transform to detect the primary orientation of lines in the bar code. Once you find the angle of the lines in the bar code, all you have to do is rotate that by 90 degrees to get the slope of a perpendicular line. The centroid of the *entire* bar code can then be used as an intercept for this line. Using the functions [HOUGH](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/hough.html) and [HOUGHPEAKS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/houghpeaks.html) from the [Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/), here's the code starting with a cropped version of your image from step 1:

```
img = imread('bar_code.jpg');  %# Load the image
img = im2bw(img);              %# Convert from RGB to BW

[H, theta, rho] = hough(img);  %# Perform the Hough transform
peak = houghpeaks(H);          %# Find the peak pt in the Hough transform
barAngle = theta(peak(2));     %# Find the angle of the bars
slope = -tan(pi*(barAngle + 90)/180);  %# Compute the perpendicular line slope

[y, x] = find(img);  %# Find the coordinates of all the white image points
xMean = mean(x);     %# Find the x centroid of the bar code
yMean = mean(y);     %# Find the y centroid of the bar code

xLine = 1:size(img,2);                   %# X points of perpendicular line
yLine = slope.*(xLine - xMean) + yMean;  %# Y points of perpendicular line

imshow(img);               %# Plot bar code image
hold on;                   %# Add to the plot
plot(xMean, yMean, 'r*');  %# Plot the bar code centroid
plot(xLine, yLine, 'r');   %# Plot the perpendicular line
```

And here's the resulting image:

[image]